# MySQLi: Fetch all from table, result has pass-by-reference

Tags: php, arrays, reference, mysqli, fetch

I'm having a problem using MySQLi, I want to create a function to return all users in the database as an Array.

Here the code:

```
public function getAll() {
    $statement = $this->database->prepare('SELECT `id`, `email`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `last_time`, `type`, `activated`, `enabled` FROM `users` ORDER BY `id`');
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($result['id'], $result['email'], $result['firstname'], $result['lastname'], $result['last_time'], $result['type'], $result['activated'], $result['enabled']);

    $users = array();

    while($statement->fetch()) {
        $users[$result['id']] = $result;
    }

    return $users;
}
```

The problem is that the `&$result` has a reference `&`, so when the `$users` Array get's filled up. Every time the while loop gets executed the previous inserted records will be updated to the last values in the `&$result` variable.
Therefore the overall result `$users` will have a list of all the same data for each record.

So how can I remove the reference from the `&$result` variable?

It works by putting each column by it's own in an new array:

```
while($statement->fetch()) {
    $users[$result['id']] = array($result['id'], $result['email'], ..etc);
}
```

But that's too much I guess, there has to be a more simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unsetting it like this:

```
$users[$result['id']] = unserialize(serialize($result));
```

Comment: One problem with your answer, serialiZe not serialiSe

Comment: Also at the `unserialize` function